# Toggle div content after a radio button is checked using CSS only

Tags: html, css

It is work when the radio buttons are same div level with "content1" and "content2", 
How to make it work, if I put radio button to another div that outside the div "second"

suppose that the toggle1 is checked then content1 will show up 
(using CSS and HTML ONLY, no javascript)

```css
.content1 {
  display: none;
}

.content2 {
  display: none;
}

.toggle1:checked ~ .grid-container .content1 {
  display: block;
}

.toggle2:checked ~ .grid-container .content2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <input type=radio id="toggle1" name="toggle" class="toggle1">
    <label for="toggle1">toggle1</label>
    <input type=radio id="toggle2" name="toggle" class="toggle2">
    <label for="toggle2">toggle2</label>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="second">
          <div class="tab content1">Content1</div>
          <div class="tab content2">Content2</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I do not see an element with class "grid-container". Also, when using the [general sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), the two elements must be "children of the same parent element."

Comment: You can't do it using only CSS given the HTML structure you have shown. Are you able to change the structure? (It sounds as though you have previously had a different structure though).

Answer (score 0):

When using the [general sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), the two elements must be "children of the same parent element." Given your existing code, apply the "grid-container" class to the `<div>` that is a sibling of the `<input>` elements.

```css
.content1,
.content2 {
  display: none;
}

.toggle1:checked ~ .grid-container .content1,
.toggle2:checked ~ .grid-container .content2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="level1">
  <div class="level2">
    <input type=radio id="toggle1" name="toggle" class="toggle1">
    <label for="toggle1">toggle1</label>
    <input type=radio id="toggle2" name="toggle" class="toggle2">
    <label for="toggle2">toggle2</label>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div>
        <div class="second">
          <div class="tab content1">Content1</div>
          <div class="tab content2">Content2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```